# Oracle SQL Variable: SELECT with STRING list of values in an IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, select

This works correctly:

```
DEFINE numbers = '1,2,3,4,5';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE items IN (&numbers);
```

As does this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE items IN ('a','b','c','d'); error
```

This returns a **snytax ERROR**:

```
DEFINE letters = 'a','b','c','d';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE items IN (&letters);  -- result syntax ERROR
```

How can I use a `WHERE ... IN` clause using a list of strings created by `DEFINE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the `DEFINE` value in double-quotes:

```
define letters = "'a','b','c','d'"

set verify on

select * from dual where dummy in (&letters);

old   1: select * from dual where dummy in (&letters)
new   1: select * from dual where dummy in ('a','b','c','d')

no rows selected
```

Note that the challenge is really how to `DEFINE` a multi-word string, as it's the same problem:

```
SQL> define letters = I love kittens
SQL> define letters
DEFINE LETTERS         = "I" (CHAR)

SQL> define letters = 'a','b','c','d'
SQL> define letters
DEFINE LETTERS         = "a" (CHAR)
```

Double-quotes fix that:

```
SQL> define letters = "I love kittens"
SQL> define letters
DEFINE LETTERS         = "I love kittens" (CHAR)
```

Just for completeness, the other way to set a `define` variable is from a `select` statement using the `column new_value` approach. Historically this was provided for setting page headings dynamically in SQL*Plus reports, but it's handy in scripts. (It's also the only way to set the type to `number`, not that it makes any difference.)

```
SQL> col letters new_value letters
SQL> select q'{'a','b','c','d'}' as letters from dual;

LETTERS
---------------
'a','b','c','d'

1 row selected.

SQL> def letters
DEFINE LETTERS         = "'a','b','c','d'" (CHAR)

SQL> select 123.456 as letters from dual;

   LETTERS
----------
   123.456

1 row selected.

SQL> def letters
DEFINE LETTERS         =    123.456 (NUMBER)
```